# Extracting compound names from many KeGG pathway documents

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, urllib

For a project, I would like to extract all compound names from many pathways on the KeGG website. The list of all pathways in a single organism looks like [this](http://rest.kegg.jp/list/pathway/eco). For every pathway, I extract the name and store the description. Then I would like to get all compounds that play a role in the pathway. Everything that is known about a KeGG pathway is found on a website like [this](http://rest.kegg.jp/get/eco00010). The elements I would like to extract are the ones listed under COMPOUND.

Basically, I have a set of urls and a very specific regular expression that I would like to extract from every URL. My question is: what is the best/ least lines/ easiest mutlithreaded web-crawling tool to get this done quickly?

My current working solution is listed below. Should I go look at scrapy (which is more for projects where you do not have a set of urls) or rather do something with threading myself?

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
from io import StringIO
import re

def get_KeGG_pathways_cpds(organism = 'eco'):
    orgURL = 'http://rest.kegg.jp/list/pathway/'
    orgStr = urllib.request.urlopen(orgURL + organism).read().decode('utf-8')
    orgIO = StringIO(orgStr)
    orgDf = pd.read_csv(orgIO, sep='\t', names  = ['pway', 'description'])

    pathURL = 'http://rest.kegg.jp/get/'    
    for pway in orgDf.pway:
        pathStr = urllib.request.urlopen(pathURL + pway).read().decode('utf-8')
        compounds = re.findall('(C[0-9]{5})', pathStr)
        print(compounds)
        print('-------------------------\n')
    return

get_KeGG_pathways_cpds()
```

Comment: I supose you want to use the API rather than the website.
https://www.kegg.jp/kegg/rest/keggapi.html

Comment: But how would one get the compounds from a pathway then? I am not familiar with REST APIs, and: http://rest.kegg.jp/get/path:eco00010/compound with urllib request does not work.

Comment: you need to use requests

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests


listed = requests.get('http://rest.kegg.jp/list/pathway/')
listed =  listed.text.split('\n') # Remove the last one which is empty
for l in listed:
     result = requests.get('http://rest.kegg.jp/get/{}'.format(l.split('\t')[0])    
     #do_thing_with_result_here(result)
     print(result.text)
```

Which shows:
ENTRY       map00010                    Pathway
NAME        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis
DESCRIPTION Glycolysis is the pro......
.......

And the rest of the pathways, which I will not copy here.